# Azure SignalR Timeout Issues

Tags: azure-signalr

I' having issues with Azure SignalR Service... Often (several times an hours) its slow and sometimes it even times out...

```
02 Jan 2019 11:37:47.1172019-01-02 14:37:47.0436 | ERROR | WebPortal | Error 

while trying to send message.  ConnectionState: Disconnected Channel: Document eventName: DocumentAccess message: Core.DTOs.Documents.RealTime.DocumentRealTimeViewModel - Exception: System.TimeoutException: Server timeout (10000.00ms) elapsed without receiving a message from the server.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.<InvokeCoreAsyncCore>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RealTimeServices.Services.RealTimeService.<SendMessageAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\home\site\repository\Dms\Services\RealTimeServices\Services\RealTimeService.cs:line 80; LogSource: RealTimeService
```

Even when doing the negotiating between the SignalR webapp and the Azure SignalR service its slow..

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: It was working fine for me but I've also suddenly starting getting timeouts. Any help will be appreciated?